# Disable tag deletion

Tags: git, tags

I have a central bare repository in which a team publish (push) their commits.
In this main repository, I want to disable the tag deletion and renaming.

Is there a solution like a hook or something ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`git help hooks` contains documentation about the hooks.  The `update` hook is invoked when Git is about to create/move/delete a reference.  It is called once per reference to be updated, and is given:

- 1st argument:  the reference name (e.g., refs/tags/v1.0)
- 2nd argument:  SHA1 of the object where the reference currently points (all zeros if the reference does not currently exist)
- 3rd argument:  SHA1 of the object where the user wants the reference to point (all zeros if the reference is to be deleted).

If the hook exits with a non-zero exit code, `git` won't update the reference and the user will get an error.

So to address your particular problem, you can add the following to your `update` hook:

```
#!/bin/sh

log() { printf '%s\n' "$*"; }
error() { log "ERROR: $*" >&2; }
fatal() { error "$*"; exit 1; }

case $1 in
    refs/tags/*)
        [ "$3" != 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 ] \
            || fatal "you're not allowed to delete tags"
        [ "$2" = 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 ] \
            || fatal "you're not allowed to move tags"
        ;;
esac
```

Comment: You might want to link to the docs or explain more about how this integrates.