# Is there a way to lock a GIT tag?

Tags: git, git-tag

I would like to be able to lock a GIT tag so that it cannot be moved or deleted for product release control. I thought I would be able to do this with a Lightweight Tag based on the [documentation](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging#Lightweight-Tags) but found by experiment that Lightweight Tags can also be moved.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable tag deletion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6390966/disable-tag-deletion)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't prevent some one from updating tags in their local copy of the repository.

You could prevent people from pushing tag updates to a remote repository by putting an `update` hook on the remote repository. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6390966/disable-tag-deletion) has some ideas that might get you started on this path.

Depending on what you're trying to do you could also consider using signed tags (`git tag -s ...`); this creates a tag that is cryptographically signed using GPG.  With an appropriate GPG configuration you can verify that a tag has been signed by a trusted party.  [This article](http://365git.tumblr.com/post/2796779828/signing-a-git-tag) discusses the use of signed tags.

Comment: This is also an interesting article on the topic of git and signed tags (and commits): https://ariejan.net/2014/06/04/gpg-sign-your-git-commits/