# Access control on Tags

Tags: git, git-tag

Does git allow to have access control on tags for creation and deletion. Similar to what it has for branches.

I want contributors to be able to create tags, but not to delete remote tags.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable tag deletion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6390966/disable-tag-deletion)

Answer (score 2):

Git has no access control. You can implement access control using Git hooks and this would work the same for branches and tags. If you use some Git hosting solution, then it is a question to the hosting solution which level of access control it allows.