# Restrict users from deleting tag in GitHub

Tags: github

Want to restrict all users in GitHub from deleting an existing tag. Please let us know if there is any way to achieve it. I have found one article where we can protect branches: https://github.com/blog/2051-protected-branches-and-required-status-check

Similarly if there is something through which we can protect tags in GitHub.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable tag deletion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6390966/disable-tag-deletion)

Comment: @DragomirKolev  That is not a valid duplicate, because github doesn't allow you to modify the git hooks for the repository

Comment: Thanks @Ferrybig I was trying to google the same but couldn't find any article for adding git hooks with GitHub to prevent tag deletion.

Comment: @DragomirKolev if you have achieve this could you please help me with reference article for GitHub.

Comment: Set you are only master user. No other one can delete tag.

Comment: There's something called Server-side hooks aswell check https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/git-hooks

Answer (score 3):

That seems to have been implemented in March 2022, as illustrated by the changelog post:

> ### [Tag protection rules](https://github.blog/changelog/2022-03-09-tag-protection-rules/)
>
> Repository owners can now configure tag protection rules to protect tags in all public repositories and in private repositories on the Pro, Teams or Enterprise plans on GitHub.
>
> **Once protected by a tag protection rule, tags matching specified patterns can only be created and deleted by users with "Maintain" or "Admin" permissions to the repository**.
>
> For more information, see [our documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/managing-your-repositorys-settings-and-features/managing-repository-settings/configuring-tag-protection-rules).

And, now in public beta:

> [Protected tags](https://github.com/github/feedback/discussions/10906)
>
> Our beta tag protection feature gives repo admins the option to protect tags on their repo.
> If they choose to do so, only maintainers and admins will be able to create these tags, and only admins will be able to modify or delete these tags.
>
> Tags are protected by patterns - you could protect all tags by using the "`*`" pattern, but you don’t have to.
>
> To set up and manage these tag protections, we’ve introduced three endpoints, which any repo admin should be able to use:
>
> ```
> GET /repos/{owner/{repo}/tags/protection
> ```
>
> Returns a list of tag protection rules.
>
> ```
> POST /repos/{owner}/{repo}/tags/protection
> ```
>
> Creates a new tag protection rule. Payload must include a pattern - example:
>
> curl -" "Authorization: token $GITHUB_TOK"N"
> -XPOST -d '{"pattern": "*"}'
> https://api.github.com/repos/JasonEtco/testing/tags/protection
>
> ```
> {
> "id": 123456,
> "pattern": "*",
> "created_at": "2022-01-12T12:01:47.094-05:00",
> "updated_at": "2022-01-12T12:01:47.094-05:00"
> }
> ```
>
> ```
> DELETE /repos/{owner}/{repo}/tags/protection/{tag_protection_id}
> ```
>
> Deletes a tag protection rule.

Answer (score 2):

GitHub currently does not support protecting tags.  This means anyone with write access to a repository can push any tag and delete any existing tag.  (Unfortunately, I could not find references for this.  Thus, I today did an experiment from an account with *Collaborator* access to a repository owned by a different account, and the Collaborator could push any tag and delete any existing tag.  Repository settings only allow protecting branches, not tags.)

There is an [open feature request in the GitHub support community](https://github.community/t/feature-request-protected-tags/1742), where a [GitHub staff member commented in February 2019](https://github.community/t/feature-request-protected-tags/1742/2) that they "are tracking an internal issue about this".

As a workaround, [GitHub support suggests](https://github.com/isaacs/github/issues/1091#issuecomment-336603313) to "set up a webhook to be notified if a tag is deleted using [their] API: https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/types/#deleteevent ".  You could create a [GitHub Actions workflow](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#on) triggered by the [`delete` event](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/events-that-trigger-workflows#delete), where you could check whether a user ([`sender` field](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/webhooks-and-events/webhook-events-and-payloads#delete)) is allowed to delete a given tag.  If deletion is not allowed, you could restore the tag.

Competing products, such as [GitLab](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/protected_tags.html) and [Bitbucket Server](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/Re-How-do-I-prevent-deletion-of-tags-from-Bitbucket-clou/qaq-p/1076164/comment-id/41775#M41775), apparently do support tag protection.