# Remove remote tags from Git even if other pushed them

Tags: git

I have created some lightweight tags in Git for testing purposes, i have (naively) pushed them, but unfortunately some colleagues (i have no idea how many) have involuntarily pulled them into their local repositories, now every time they `push`, those tags will reappear in remote repository.
I am wondering if there is a way to remove tags from remote Git in a final way, so that even if someone else pushes them, they will not be stored.
Sorry for not posting any code, but i dont know where to start from.
 I have checked the Git documentation but i have not found anything that can help my case.
Thank you

Comment: Hooks might get you there. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6390966/453616) and its [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6391028/453616) might a useful starting point.